# Add new lines to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlwriter

I have a program that creates an XML log. First I check if the XML exists, and if not I use the following code to create it:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(myXMLLog, settings))
                    {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteComment("Comment here.");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Batch");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", BatchID);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", now);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Step");
                    writer.WriteElementString("Name", step);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Success", success);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Message", message);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Transaction");
                    writer.WriteElementString("ID", transID);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Details", details);

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                }
```

This works as expected and creates the file:

```
<!--This log was created by the Application.-->
<Batch Date="1/22/2014 10:01:11 PM" ID="166bf0d2-3bd4-4353-b309-20b6d0d59a93">
<Step>
   <Name>Start Batch</Name>
   <Success>1</Success>
   <Message>Processing Batch</Message>
<Transaction>
   <ID>N/A</ID>
   <Details>N/A</Details>
</Transaction>
</Step>
```

So the second time around, it checks that the XML exists, it does, so instead of creating it  should just add to it. I'm using the following code for this:

```
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(myXMLLog);
                XElement root = new XElement("Batch");

                root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", BatchID));
                root.Add(new XAttribute("Date", now));
                root.Add(new XElement("Step"));
                root.Add(new XAttribute("Name", step));
                root.Add(new XAttribute("Success", success));
                root.Add(new XAttribute("Message", message));
                root.Add(new XElement("Transaction"));
                root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", transID));
                root.Add(new XAttribute("Details", details));

                xmlDoc.Element("Batch").Add(root);
                xmlDoc.Save(myXMLLog);
```

So now I'm expecting the XML file to look something like this:

```
<!--This log was created by the Application.-->
<Batch Date="1/22/2014 10:01:11 PM" ID="166bf0d2-3bd4-4353-b309-20b6d0d59a93">
<Step>
   <Name>Start Batch</Name>
   <Success>1</Success>
   <Message>Processing Batch</Message>
<Transaction>
   <ID>N/A</ID>
   <Details>N/A</Details>
</Transaction>
</Step>
</Batch>
<Batch Date="1/22/2014 10:20:00 PM" ID="166bf0d2-3bd4-4353-b309-20b6d0d5aaa">
<Step>
   <Name>Start Batch</Name>
   <Success>1</Success>
   <Message>Processing Batch</Message>
<Transaction>
   <ID>N/A</ID>
   <Details>N/A</Details>
</Transaction>
</Step>
</Batch>
```

But instead I get an exception "Duplicate Attribute".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The XML Document does has  at the top of it. Valid XML would be very nice, but not a most.

**EDIT EDIT:**

This is how my code looks now:

```
            if (File.Exists(myXMLLog))
            {              
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(myXMLLog);
                XElement root = new XElement("Batch",
                    new XAttribute("ID", BatchID),
                    new XAttribute("Date", now),
                    new XElement("Step",
                        new XElement("Name", step),
                        new XElement("Success", success),
                        new XElement("Message", message),
                        new XElement("Transaction",
                            new XAttribute("IDTrans", transID),
                            new XAttribute("Details", details))));
                xmlDoc.Root.Add(root);
                xmlDoc.Save(myXMLLog);
            }
            else
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(myXMLLog, settings))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();

                    writer.WriteComment("This log was created by the Application.");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Batch");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", BatchID);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", now);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Step");
                    writer.WriteElementString("Name", step);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Success", success);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Message", message);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Transaction");
                    writer.WriteElementString("IDTrans", transID);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Details", details);

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                }
            }
```

I'm ok with the format of the XML, my problem now is that is doing the BATCH inside the first BATCH

```
<Batch Date="1/22/2014 11:49:17 PM" ID="6966578b-b326-4f16-a315-1b4228a9fa42">
<Step><Name>Create DataTable</Name>
<Success>1</Success>
<Message>DataTable was Created and Populated</Message>
<Transaction>
<IDTrans>N/A</IDTrans>
<Details>0</Details>
</Transaction>
</Step>
<Batch Date="1/22/2014 11:49:17 PM" ID="6966578b-b326-4f16-a315-1b4228a9fa42">
<Step>
<Name>Send Email</Name>
<Success>1</Success>
<Message>Template Seleted and Filled</Message>
<Transaction Details="Email To: email@email.com Link:  " IDTrans="243b0a3c-d8b7-49c3-b1d0-asdfsdsdfsdf"/>
</Step>
</Batch>.....
```

***EDIT FINAL***

Working Code, combination of all answers:

```
            if (File.Exists(myXMLLog))
            {              
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(myXMLLog);
                XElement root = new XElement("Batch",
                    new XAttribute("ID", BatchID),
                    new XAttribute("Date", now),
                    new XElement("Step",
                        new XElement("Name", step),
                        new XElement("Success", success),
                        new XElement("Message", message),
                        new XElement("Transaction",
                            new XAttribute("IDTrans", transID),
                            new XAttribute("Details", details))));
                xmlDoc.Root.Add(root);
                xmlDoc.Save(myXMLLog);
            }
            else
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(myXMLLog, settings))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteComment("This log was created by the Application.");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Batch");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", BatchID);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Date", now);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Step");
                    writer.WriteElementString("Name", step);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Success", success);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Message", message);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Transaction");
                    writer.WriteElementString("IDTrans", transID);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Details", details);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                }
            }
```

I'm happy with the results. If anyone has suggestions on how to better format the XML, please do so. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Side note: whatever you trying to create is not XML, it is collection of XML fragments (since it lacks root node). It can't be read with default XML readers, but if needed you can configure .Net `XmlReader` to expect "XML fragment" instead of document. Similar append-friendly XML-fragments format used by some loggers...

Comment: Consider updating your question whether you want valid XML or format you currently asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code adds all these elements and attributes to `root`, instead of adding some attributes to newly created elements.

Element creation should look like that:

```
XElement root = new XElement("Batch",
    new XAttribute("ID", BatchID),
    new XAttribute("Date", now),
    new XElement("Step",
        new XElement("Name", step),
        new XElement("Success", success),
        new XElement("Message", message),
        new XElement("Transaction",
            new XElement("ID", transID),
            new XElement("Details", details))));
```

Comment: I think Name,Success and Message should be XElement

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add two ID attributes to the same Batch element.

```
   root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", BatchID));
   root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", transID));
```

I guess you need an `ID` and `Details` element inside of your `Transaction` element so do this when you adding your Transaction element:

```
root.Add(new XElement("Transaction",
             new XElement("ID", transID),
             new XElement("Details",details));
```

Also you can do all of these in one statement:

```
XElement root = new XElement("Batch",
            new XAttribute("ID", BatchID),
            new XAttribute("Date", now),
            new XElement("Step",
                new XElement("Success", success),
                new XElement("Message", message),
                new XElement("Transaction",
                    new XElement("ID", transID),
                    new XElement("Details", details))));
```

Note: As MarcinJuraszek mentioned his answer you are adding all attributes directly to your root element.For example:

```
root.Add(new XElement("Step"));
root.Add(new XAttribute("Name", step));
root.Add(new XAttribute("Success", success));
```

That code doesn't add `Name` and `Success` attribute to your `Step` element, it adds these two attribute to your root element.To fix this you need to add these attribute to your `Step` element when you creating it:

```
XElement stepElement = new XElement("Step",
                           new XAttribute("Name", step),
                           new XAttribute("Success", success));
```

Then you can add this element to the root:

```
root.Add(stepElement);
```

And a final note you should use `XElement` to add new Elements, according to your XML document,`Name,Success,Message,Id (transaction)` and `Details` should be `XElement` not `XAttribute.`

Answer (score 2):

First you have two "ID" properties, please remove either of them:

```
root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", BatchID));
……………………
root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", transID));
```

Then you CANNOT do that because your xml lacks of a head root. I mean you should change your xml file something like this by adding a "Root" as the root head of your xml

```
<!--This log was created by the BaswareVendorRegistrationCA Application.-->
<Root>
  <Batch Date="1/22/2014 10:01:11 PM" ID="166bf0d2-3bd4-4353-b309-20b6d0d59a93">
    <Step>
      <Name>Start Batch</Name>
      <Success>1</Success>
      <Message>Processing Batch</Message>
      <Transaction>
        <ID>N/A</ID>
        <Details>N/A</Details>
      </Transaction>
    </Step>
  </Batch>
</Root>
```

Then do appending:

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
            XElement root = new XElement("Batch");

            root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", 1));
            root.Add(new XAttribute("Date", 2));
            root.Add(new XElement("Step"));
            root.Add(new XAttribute("Name", 3));
            root.Add(new XAttribute("Success", 4));
            root.Add(new XAttribute("Message", 5));
            root.Add(new XElement("Transaction"));
            root.Add(new XAttribute("Details", 7));

            xmlDoc.Root.Add(root);
            xmlDoc.Save("c:\\try.xml");
```

PS: If your xml DOESN'T have a root element, VS will tell you that's an INVALID xml:

[image]